# Angular Cli aplication stops loading when routing is added

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying a new Angular-Cli aplication and for some reason when I add the routes, the main page (dashboard) stops loading

here's the component i'm adding the route to:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OrganizationService } from './shared/organization.service';
import {Organization} from "./shared/organization";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-organization',
  templateUrl: './organizations.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./organizations.component.scss']
})
export class OrganizationsComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string;
  organization: Organization = new Organization();
  constructor(
    private organizationService: OrganizationService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    var id = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      var id = params['id'];
      this.title = id ? 'Edit Faq Organization' : 'Create Faq Organization';
      if (!id)
        return;
      this.organizationService.getOrganization(id)
        .subscribe(
          organization => this.organization = organization,
          response => {});
    });
  }
  save() {
    var result;
    if (this.organization.id){
      result = this.organizationService.updateOrganization(this.organization);
    } else {
      result = this.organizationService.addOrganization(this.organization);
    }
    result.subscribe(data => this.router.navigate(['/']));
  }
}
```

This is the model:

```
export class Organization {
  id: number;
  nome: string;
  sigla: string;
  cnpj: string;
}
```

And this is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class OrganizationService {
  private url: string = "http://localhost:3000/organizations";
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getOrganizations(){
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
  getOrganization(id){
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/' + id)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
  addOrganization(organization){
    return this.http.post(this.url, {'organization': organization})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  updateOrganization(organization){
    return this.http.put(this.url + '/' + organization.id, {'organization': organization})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
  deleteOrganization(id){
    return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + id)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

And the route:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';


//Layouts
import { OrganizationsComponent } from './organizations/organizations.component';
import { FullLayoutComponent } from './layouts/full-layout.component';


export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: FullLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Página Inicial'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
      },
    ]
  },
  //THIS IS THE PART THAT MAKES THE PAGE NOT LOAD
  { path: 'organizations/new', component: OrganizationsComponent},
  { path: 'organizations/:id', component: OrganizationsComponent},
  { path: 'organizations/:id/edit', component: OrganizationsComponent},
];


export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I'm new to rails and angular, sorry if I'm missing something obvious!

Thanks!

@Edit
Here's my app.module too:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { TabsModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/tabs';
import { NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES } from './shared/nav-dropdown.directive';

import { SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES } from './shared/sidebar.directive';
import { AsideToggleDirective } from './shared/aside.directive';
import { BreadcrumbsComponent } from './shared/breadcrumb.component';

// Routing Module
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';

//Layouts
import { FullLayoutComponent } from './layouts/full-layout.component';
import { OrganizationsComponent } from './organizations/organizations.component';
import { OrganizationService } from './organizations/shared/organization.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FullLayoutComponent,
    NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
    BreadcrumbsComponent,
    SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES,
    AsideToggleDirective,
//    OrganizationsComponent
  ],
  providers: [OrganizationService,
  {
    provide: LocationStrategy,
    useClass: HashLocationStrategy
  }],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }


// Dependências do Angular 2
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

// Adicionamos o arquivo routing
import { routing } from './app.routing';
```

Comment: Could you please post the route config of your angular router module?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the most important part haha, just added it! ty

Comment: One more thing, could you also add your app.module.ts file? Is it possible that the `OrganizationsComponent` has not been added to the `NgModule.declarations` array?

Comment: Also I noticed that you have two routes with `path: ''`. Are you sure this does not lead to an error? (check your browsers console)

Comment: if I remove the `{ path: 'organizations/new', component: OrganizationsComponent},
  { path: 'organizations/:id', component: OrganizationsComponent},
  { path: 'organizations/:id/edit', component: OrganizationsComponent},` part, the page loads

Comment: Should the `OrganizationsComponent` in the declarations block really be commented out?

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the `OrganizationsComponent` is commented out.

```ts
@NgModule({
  // ...
  declarations: [
    // ...
    // FIX HERE: This should not be commented out.
    OrganizationsComponent
  ],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: yep, I commented that while testing, if I uncomment that, the problem persists, the page doesn't load. I need to comment the declaration and the routes to make it load.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I was missing the forms module import

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```